# back tracking way through search tree

Tags: python, tree, combinatorics

I have the following problem:

I have a dictionary of parents and their possible childs, for example:
{'baritone': ['baritones', 'reobtains', 'obtainers']}.

I already wrote a function for finding the possible parents of a child:

```
def find_parents(node, tree):
    allpar = list()
    for parent, childs in tree.items():
         if node in childs:
             allpar.append(parent)
    return allpar
```

find_parents('baritone', mytree) returns ['baritones', 'reobtains', 'obtainers']

given a certain child and parent anywhere in the tree I now want to find the shortest way. I already know the shortest path length, while not knowing the path itself.

Comment: "I already know the shortest path length" show us your code for that. Also check out NetworkX.

Comment: I am building the list of items iteratively. I therefore now how many iteration steps it takes for the child to appear in the list. Code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/68134747?noredirect=1